# Cloned html markup lost events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have invisible TR row which is cloned by jQuery by function clone(true, true) as $cloned but onclick events on some elements inside TR are lost.
Then I append into correct TABLE by:

```js
jQuery(parent).closest('table').find('tbody').append($cloned);
```

What to check next or todo to clone events?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Old: That's by design, cloning does not copy event handlers.

New: Apparently, jQuery cloning does copy event handlers. While two options below are still valid approach, there might be some closure as event handler which holds "wrong" (from new nodes' point of view) references, and thus event handlers appear to be non-working.

Two options:

1. Clone and then re-assign handlers. If your code is well-written, that usually not a problem.
2. Bind your event handlers to outer container, possible to body or document, e.g.:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.my-special-button', (e) => { ... });
```

Second approach might also require some rewriting. Still, it's a valid option. To find out more, look for "delegated event handlers" e.g. here: https://api.jquery.com/on/.

Both rules can be followed at the same time, that would be even better.

Comment: _"cloning does not copy event handlers"_ It does when you pass true as parameters like the OP says they are

Comment: You're right, I must have confused jQuery clone with DOM cloneNode where deep does not mean "include event handlers". I should correct my reply.